# `qdbus` command does not apply until scripts exits

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, manjaro

I have a script which I use to make it easier for me to connect to the many servers I need to SSH into. It's working well except that the terminal's title (Konsole tab title in my case) is being set to the name of my script, "() ./scripts/ssh". I updated the script and added a call to `qdbus` to set the Konsole tab title. It works, but only after the SSH session is closed / the script completes.

How do I make the `qdbus` command take affect immediately?

### the script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ENV=$1
HOST=$2
USER=${3:-my_username}

if [ -z ${ENV} ]; then
  echo "First parameter must be the environment."
  exit -1
fi

if [ -z ${HOST} ]; then
  echo "Second parameter must be the host."
  exit -1
fi

case "$ENV" in
  # cases to determine proper hostname from abbreviated input
  *)
    echo "Unsupported environment: ${ENV}"
    exit -1
esac

HOST="${HOST}.${ENV}.net"

# set tab title
qdbus >/dev/null "${KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE}" ${KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION} setTabTitleFormat 0 "${USER}@${HOST}"

echo "Connecting to ${HOST} as ${USER} ..."
ssh ${USER}@${HOST}

# revert tab title -- COMMENTED OUT FOR TESTING
# qdbus >/dev/null "${KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE}" ${KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION} setTabTitleFormat 0 "%w"
```

When I run my script ...

1. tab text is updated to `() ./scripts/ssh`
2. "Connecting" echo is displayed
3. I'm SSH'd in per usual
4. tab text is not updated

When I exit the SSH session, the tab text is set to `"${USER}@${HOST}"` as in the command above (before `ssh`).

I have added / comment out a line which reverts the tab text back to what it was before I ran the script (I think).

Comment: do you see anything interesting if you remove the `>/dev/null`? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Removing that appears to have no affect.